# XMLHttpRequest ontimeout problem in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, timeout, settimeout

In my react.js project `Profile` class I have a function called `getData`, here is what it look like :

```
getData()
{
    console.log("inside get data");
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.timeout=1000;
    request.ontimeout=function () {
        console.log("on timeout");
    };
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/user/'.concat(this.state.userID));
    request.send();
}
```

I have also tried this :

```
    request.setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("on timeout");
            that.props.history.push("/bad_request/".concat(this.status));

    },1000);
```

But it gives me error saying `TypeError: request.setTimeout is not a function`

I have also bind the method :

`this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);`

I call it from `componentWillMount`.

This logs few things in the console. But never *on timeout*.

What is the problem? How this can be resolved ?

Comment: `setTimeout` is a global method and has nothing to do with `XMLHttpRequest`. It's not really clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Are you sure your endpoint is going to take longer than 1 second to reply? local servers are going to return a response pretty quickly unless you already set it up to stall. Otherwise try a very low number like 1 (for 1 millisecond) or add code to the server endpoint to make it stall longer than a second

Comment: I used one second just to debug quickly .

Comment: @charlietfl solved the problem . But one more thing if I add `that.props.history.push("/bad_request/".concat(this.status));` the line after `console.log("on timeout");` it gives me error saying *TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined* as this is currently indicating that method. How this can be resolved?

Comment: I have edited the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
switch (xmlhttp.readyState) {
      case 0 : // UNINITIALIZED
      case 1 : // LOADING
      case 2 : // LOADED
      case 3 : // INTERACTIVE
      break;
      case 4 : // COMPLETED
      doSomething()
      break;
      default: // catch error here
   }
```

I'm using this to check if it is status and finally I can check if the server has timed out or not as default will give me different types of error.